# Computing remainder of polynomial division

Tags: c, reduction, modular

Does the following code implement modular reduction of the polynomial multiplication of f•g modulo *x*<sup>*p*</sup>−*x*−1? As we know, to get the modular reduction, we first multiply the polynomials f and g, then divide by *x*<sup>*p*</sup>−*x*−1, and the remainder is the result h = f•g.

I could not see how the code below does this. The degrees of the polynomials are at most *p*−1, i.e., they look like f(*x*) = 1+*x*−*x*<sup>2</sup>+....−x<sup>*p*−1</sup> which is represented as an array `f[p]` = {1, 1, -1,... -1}. And array `h` = `fg[p+p-2]` stands for the product of f and g.

Can someone explain this to me?

```
for (i = p+p-2;i >= p;--i) 
{
    fg[i-p] = fg[i-p]+fg[i];
    fg[i-p+1] = fg[i-p+1]+fg[i];
}
for (i = 0;i < p;++i) h[i] = fg[i];
```

Comment: Where did you get that code? Was there any context given, a comment, a description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the following code stand for modular reduction of the polynomial multiplication of f.g by mod (x^p-x-1)?

Yes.

> The degree of the polynomials are at most p-1, i.e., they look like f(x)= 1+x-x^2+....-x^{p-1} which is shown as an array f[p]={1,1,-1,...,-1}.

No, the reduced polynomial has degree at most *p*−1, but this is code to reduce the result of a multiplication. Two polynomials of degree up to *p*−1 have been multiplied, producing a polynomial of degree up to 2*p*−2, and the job of this code is to take the remainder modulo *x*<sup>*p*</sup>−*x*−1.

To do this, `i` iterates through the degrees from 2*p*−2 (written `p+p-2`) to *p*. It starts at 2*p*−2 since that is the highest degree that might be present in the product, and it stops at *p* since that is the lowest degree for which there is a quotient whose multiple can be subtracted.

Then, for each degree `i`, it subtracts a multiple of *x*<sup>*p*</sup>−*x*−1: Let *c* be the coefficient of *x*<sup>`i`</sup>, `fg[i]`. Then this code subtracts *c*•*x*<sup>*i*−*p*</sup>•(*x*<sup>*p*</sup>−*x*−1) = *c*•*x*<sup>*i*</sup> − *c*•*x*<sup>*i*−*p*+1</sup> − *c*•*x*<sup>*i*−*p*</sup>:

- Subtracting *c*•*x*<sup>*i*</sup> would yield zero in `fg[i]`. This is implemented simply by ignoring the coefficients at indices `p` and above; they are not copied into the `h` result by the loop at the end.
- − *c*•*x*<sup>*i*−*p*+1</sup> is subtracted by adding *c* (`fg[i]`) to the coefficient of *x*<sup>*i*−*p*+1</sup>, in the code `fg[i-p+1] = fg[i-p+1]+fg[i];`.
- − *c*•*x*<sup>*i*−*p*</sup> is subtracted by adding  *c* (`fg[i]`) to the coefficient of *x*<sup>*i*−*p*</sup>, in the code `fg[i-p] = fg[i-p]+fg[i];`.

When the first `for` loop completes, all multiples of the polynomial have been subtracted from the initial product, leaving only the remainder.

Then `for (i = 0;i < p;++i) h[i] = fg[i];` simply copies the new coefficients into `h`.